# return data in a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got the following json object:

```
$dati = array(
    "data" => array(
        'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
        'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
        'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
        'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
        'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
    ),
    "str" => array("n".$i=>$array_db[username]),
    "index" => $i
);
```

I want to show *str* data. So I've wrote:

```
... success:function(msg){
        if(msg){
                var j = "n"+2;
                $("#location").html(msg.str.j);
        }else{
            $("#location").html('Not Available');
        }
    },
```

but the output is empty. Instead if I don't use variable *j* in *$("#location").html(msg.str.j);* but `$("#location").html(msg.str.n2);`
it work correctly. Why this?

Comment: I tried and the output is: [object Object]n2

Comment: var allitesms = JSON.parse(msg.str); and just iterate allItems.

Comment: can you write the complete code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to attach string to a Object.

You are trying to do something like this msg.str.'n2' which is not same as msg.str.n2.

I will give you working example right now:

```
var object = {
    name: 'Aleksandar',
    lastname: 'Djokic'
};
alert(object.name);
```

result of this is "Aleksandar"

Now this :

```
var object = {
    name: 'Aleksandar',
    lastname: 'Djokic'
};
var something = 'name';
alert(object.something);
```

Result of this alert is "undefined".

update: for array in object:

```
var object = {
    name: 'aleksandar',
    lastname: 'djokic',
    arr: ['first','second','third']
};
for(var i = 0; i<object.arr.length; i++) {
    alert(object.arr[i]);
}
```

if you want to get it by key then use :

```
var something = 'n2'; 
alert(msg.str[something]);
```

Correct solution :

```
... success:function(msg){
        if(msg){
                var j = "n"+2;
                $("#location").html(msg.str[j]);
        }else{
            $("#location").html('Not Available');
        }
    },
```

Comment: no but I ask if there is any solution or an other type of method

Comment: i edited my aswer.please try this and let me know if you have any questions. @Fabio97

Comment: `$dati = array("str"=>array("n1"=>"fabio", "n2"=>"marco","n3"=>"alex"));` and I want to show **marco** as output using a variable as index of array.

Comment: var something = 'n2';     alert(msg.str[something]); @Fabio97